# Distinguish missing property vs null value on property C#

Tags: .net, json

I have problem with update in database. When i do update i send only the properties of the object that i want to change but when the user clears property i send it as null and the property in the JSON is not missing. In the class mapper missing properties are represented as null and null properties are also null. How can i distinguish between missing property and null property sent by user?

```
{
    surname: 'Something else', 
}   

{
    surname: null, 
}
```

when i send null i want to set some flag that i need to update this field in database as null and not to ignore it as not changed

Comment: Well one option is not to map to a normal .NET object to start with - use LINQ to JSON (part of Json.NET for example) and then you can easily see which fields have been provided...

Comment: You can always pass a default, agreed upon value which isn't `null`.

Comment: I have application layer, structure and core layer and when the object gets to core layer i need to know which field i have to set to null

Comment: Thanks i solved the problem with LINQ to JSON by inspecting if property is set.